# Does ArcGIS Pro join to excel worksheets like ArcMap does?

Tags: excel, arcgis-pro

I love the idea of ArcGIS Pro, especially for non-GIS analysts to get one-off maps done easily and quickly.

The big question is: Does ArcGIS Pro join to excel worksheets like ArcMap does?

Comment: I think you'd get better answers for this question [on GeoNet](https://geonet.esri.com/community/gis/applications/arcgis-pro), not many Esri employees are on gis.stackexchange.

Comment: @JasonScheirer wish I could plus 100 that comment.

Comment: Thats, @JasonScheirer.  TBH I didn't know if anyone had explored it and wanted to avoid and Esri upselling.

Answer (score 4):

At this time ArcGIS Pro cannot see or use Excel spreadsheets. This functionality might be added later, but I haven't seen any firm indication of when that might be.  It is currently in Pre-release and due to come out with ArcGIS 10.3.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it does now but it's not as robust (compared to mapinfo which does this very easily). See https://community.esri.com/groups/esri-training/blog/2017/05/26/working-with-excel-data-in-arcgis-pro

Comment: BTW: Works in 2.4 but not as robust or easy as Mapinfo e.g. you can't choose the field types as you add the excel data in.